# Synchronous Task Processing only for Same Users

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a web api which process payments (and manage user accounts) from different channels. The problem I am facing is that if the same user is transacting from different channels - the accounts & balances go for a toss.

eg consider this scenario happening all in one second with overlapping execution times:

- R1 - User1 withdraw 100
- R2 - User2 withdraw 10
- R3 - User1 withdraw 50
- R4 - User3 withdraw 20
- R5 - User2 withdraw 100
- R6 - User4 withdraw 20

Thats because all the accounts were processed at the same time with disastrous results. I introduced Thread locking (lock & Monitor/TryEnter) but that will mean all requests go in one single queue. Even if the User4 didnt have anything to do with others, it had to wait all other requests to finish.

```
public class PaymentProcessor
{
    private static object _lockobject = new object();
    public void process() {
        if (Monitor.TryEnter(_lockobject, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)))
        {
            ProcessRequest(xmlData); //ignore xmlData
            Monitor.Exit(_lockobject);
        }
    }
}
```

Ideally, I would like separate queues for User1 & User2 requests and rest to be processed at the same time.

Ideally queues

- R1, R3
- R2, R5
- R3
- R4

How do I achieve this?

cheers

Comment: For who come here with a similar problem - the SP was bit badly coded not locking records in SELECT as well as UPDATE. I fixed the transaction and things are working now

Answer (score 3):

Locking access to the account at the level of WebApi code is absolutely wrong way. You kill performance and make your system defenseless in the face of malicious requests. Even worse, this is absolutely not reliable (for example, in case of IIS usage) because of unpredictable thread pool recycling.

What you need is usage of transaction at the level of database. After transaction started and account is locked, balance should be check and after this appropriate changes could be made.

Comment: I have implemented rowlock, updlock at rowlevel in the db but somehow its not serving the purpose at all.
BEGIN TRANSACTION  trans
UPDATE PlayerBalance WITH (UPDLOCK, ROWLOCK) SET availableBalance=@ClosingBal WHERE ID=@PID
COMMIT TRANSACTION  trans 

But it doesnt seem to work. Transactions hitting within  50-100 ms also post overlapping requests. Thats why I resorted to threading in code. 

I am not sure if I am doing it the wrong way.

Comment: You have several ways to implement transaction correctly depending on architecture of your application. The key moment is to lock what you really have to lock.  Without seeing the code, for SQL Server I can advise to look at sp_lock stored procedure MSDN documentation.

Comment: I made a mistake, not sp_lock but sp_getapplock and sp_releaseapplock. :)